# sorting json nested array using values from another nested array

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am getting json data using a php script and the output looks something like this -

```
api":{
  "status":200
  "message":"GET ...."
  "results":15
  "filters":[...]
  "standings":[
     0:{
        "league":"standard"
        "teamId":"1"
        "seasonYear":"2018"
        "conference":{4 items
               "name":"east"
               "rank":"12"
               "win":"16"
               "loss":"36"
}
        "division":{
               "name":"southeast"
               "rank":"5"
               "win":"6"
               "loss":"10"
}
       "winPercentage":".354"
       "lossPercentage":".646"
}
1:{...} ...
```

And I am trying to sort the "standings" array using the value from `standings->conference->rank` key/value.

This is what I've tried -

```
..
$response = 'api url';
$items = json_decode($response->body->api->standings);
foreach ($items as $item) {
usort($item,function($a, $b) {
    return $a->conference->rank < $b->conference->rank ? -1 : 1;
  });

echo $item->conference->rank;
}
```

but it isnt outputting anything. And without `json_decode` it outputs the original order. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to `json_decode` a json string. I assume `$response->body` is your string, so you do:

```
$result = json_decode($response->body);
```

Next, you don't need to iterate the array, the `usort` function will do it for you.

```
usort($result->api->standings, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->conference->rank - $b->conference->rank;
});
```

Example with output: https://3v4l.org/JDt2S

Comment: hi thanks, however i tried your suggestion and it didnt output anything.

Comment: @Rich You can see the output with `print_r`

Comment: @Rich I've added an example with output

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php 7+, you can use spaceship(<=>) operator

```
$items = json_decode($response->body->api->standings);
usort($item,function($a, $b) {
    return $a->conference->rank <=> $b->conference->rank;
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7vNiU)

PHP 5.6 or lesser

```
$items = ($arr->api->standings);
usort($items,function($a, $b) {
    if($a->conference->rank == $b->conference->rank){
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->conference->rank < $b->conference->rank) ? -1 : 1;
});
print_r($items);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/mTXW2)